# Apache's HttpAsyncClient never returns after execute

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, asynchttpclient

I'm writing a web scraper for a particular site with HttpAsyncClient and Jsoup. I'm using one instance of HttpAsyncClient which executes several requests from different threads. After a few successful requests, it seems that the client hangs and won't execute more requests. The invocation of the `execute` method returns the `FutureCallback` object normally, but neither of its methods (`completed`, `failed` or `cancelled`) is ever executed.

By looking at the log it seems as if the request is never sent:

```
33572 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec  - [exchange: 5] start execution
33573 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  - CookieSpec selected: default
33575 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  - Cookie [version: 0][name: .ASPXAUTH][value: removed][domain: www.predictit.org][path: /][expiry: null] match [(secure)www.predictit.org:443/Home/SingleOption]
33576 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  - Cookie [version: 0][name: ARRAffinity][value: removed][domain: www.predictit.org][path: /][expiry: null] match [(secure)www.predictit.org:443/Home/SingleOption]
33577 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  - Cookie [version: 0][name: ASP.NET_SessionId][value: removed][domain: www.predictit.org][path: /][expiry: null] match [(secure)www.predictit.org:443/Home/SingleOption]
33579 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  - Cookie [version: 0][name: __RequestVerificationToken][value: removed][domain: www.predictit.org][path: /][expiry: null] match [(secure)www.predictit.org:443/Home/SingleOption]
33579 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache  - Auth cache not set in the context
33580 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient  - [exchange: 5] Request connection for {s}->https://www.predictit.org:443
33580 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager  - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://www.predictit.org:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
33581 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl  - http-outgoing-0 192.168.1.6:38559<->23.96.96.142:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: Set timeout 0
33581 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager  - Connection leased: [id: http-outgoing-0][route: {s}->https://www.predictit.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
33582 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient  - [exchange: 5] Connection allocated: CPoolProxy{http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]}
33582 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl  - http-outgoing-0 192.168.1.6:38559<->23.96.96.142:443[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: Set attribute http.nio.exchange-handler
33583 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl  - http-outgoing-0 192.168.1.6:38559<->23.96.96.142:443[ACTIVE][rw:r][ACTIVE][rw][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0][0]: Event set [w]
```

It just hangs there at the last line and nothing happens. It seems to be some sort of deadlock but the CloseableHttpAsyncClient is supposed to be thread safe.

You can see the code [here](http://pastebin.com/sBSscSby) and you can run it yourself (it has a main method) if you create a maven project with [these](http://pastebin.com/MSbB6wW6) dependencies.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was causing a deadlock by invoking the `execute` method inside the `completed` method of a FutureCallback returned by the same HttpAsyncClient. I changed the code so that the `completed` method just returns a list of links that are processed after the method completes and everything works now.

Comment: Issue and workaround is documented here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1805